# What is the best lib to use for zero knowledge application?

Tags: solidity, zero-knowledge

This is a simple smart contract I found in the internet for a zero knowledge applications.

But there is no libs imported.

What is the best lib to use in this situation?
Can openzeppelin solve this problem?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

// Smart contract for a zero knowledge application
contract ZeroKnowledge {
    // The proving key for the zero knowledge proof
    ProvingKey public provingKey;
    // The verifier contract for the zero knowledge proof
    Verifier public verifier;

    // Constructor to initialize the smart contract with the proving key and verifier
    constructor(ProvingKey _provingKey, Verifier _verifier) public {
        provingKey = _provingKey;
        verifier = _verifier;
    }

    // Function to allow users to submit a zero knowledge proof
    function submitProof(uint[] memory proof) public {
        require(verifier.verifyProof(proof, provingKey.pk()));
        // Perform some action based on the successful verification of the proof
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is too broad. Do you have something in mind, a particular use case?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't look to someone like OZ for these kinds of solutions, since their work is directed towards Etheruem itself, and not ZK/L2 rollups per sé.

Check [here](https://github.com/matter-labs/awesome-zero-knowledge-proofs) for a guide which I used to better my knowledge of ZK, including some fun tutorials, and to break into the popular [gnark](https://github.com/ConsenSys/gnark) ZK library from Concensys.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you @XaEk for helping me!